# Exercises on the field extension $E := \mathbb{F}_3[X]/(X^2 + X + 2)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, solution-verification, extension-field, splitting-field

We consider the polynomial $p(X) := X^2 + X + 2$ in the ring $\mathbb{F}_3[X]$.

(a) Show that $E := \mathbb{F}_3[X]/ p(X)$ is a finite field extension of $\mathbb{F}_3$.

(b) Determine a basis of $E$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{F}_3$. For all elements of $E$, give their multiplicative inverses.

(c) Using the polynomial $q(X) := X^2 + 2X + 2$, we continue to consider the finite field extension $F := \mathbb{F}_3[X]/ q(X)$ of $\mathbb{F}_3$. Determine a field isomorphism $ϕ: E → F$ that leaves $\mathbb{F}_3$ fixed element-wise.

For a) my idea was  to check the field extension $\mathbb{F}_3(a)/\mathbb{F}_3$ where $a$ is a root of the polynomial $p(X)$. Since $\mathbb{F}_3(a)/\mathbb{F}_3$ is isomorphic to $ \mathbb{F}_3[X]/ p(X)$ if we can show that is a finite field extension we have the answer . I can prove that is a field extension since $p(X)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_3$ and since $p(X)$ is an irreducible polynomial of degree $2$ $\mathbb{F}_3(a)/\mathbb{F}_3$ is a finite field extension and therefore (because of $\mathbb{F}_3(a)/\mathbb{F}_3 \cong E$) we have that $E$ is a finite field extension. So far everything right?

For b) I dont know how to proceed. I know that every element of E can be rapresented as $e=a+bp(X)$ where $a,b \in \mathbb{F}_3[X]$, but from here I dont know how to proceed. Can someone help me?

For c) I have really no idea.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Hint for (b): It is a nice observation that $E\cong \mathbb{F}_3(a)$. For a simple extension $K(a)/K$, what is a basis of $K(a)$ as a $K$-vector space? This should be well-known. (If you do not know the result, then there is a hint: Every $x\in K(a)$ is $K-$linear combination of finitely many members of $S=\{1,a,a^2,\cdots,a^n\}$. What can you say about whether members in $S$ are linear independent when $a$ is algebraic/ transcedental over $K$?)

Comment: @Asigan Using the "well known" basis of $K(a)$ feels kind like a circular argument to me. The usual proof that $\{1,a,a^2,...,a^{n-1}\}$ is indeed a basis uses the fact that $K(a)$ is isomorphic as a $K$-algebra to $K[x]/(m_a)$ where $m_a$ is the minimal polynomial of $a$. Finding a basis for the quotient $K[x]/(f)$ is something really straightforward, and doesn't require using roots.

Comment: @Mark I think there is a direct proof: (1) $\{1,a,a^2,...,a^{n-1}\}$ spans $K(a)$ since $a^n$ is a linear combination of $\{1,a,a^2,...,a^{n-1}\}$, $a^{n+1}=aa^n$ is therefore a linear span of $\{1,a,a^2,...,a^{n-1}, a^n\}$, and is therefore a linear span of $\{1,a,a^2,...,a^{n-1}\}$, and we can use induction. (2) $\{1,a,a^2,...,a^{n-1}\}$ is linear independent because the irreducible polynomial has the least degree that admit $a$ is a zero, i.e. no non-zero polynomial with degree less than or equal $n-1$ admits $a$ as a zero.

Comment: @Asigan It can indeed be proved directly, even without induction. First it has to be shown that $K(a)=K[a]$, so a general element takes the form $f(a)$, for some $f\in K[x]$. By dividing $f$ by $m_a$ with remainder we get $f(a)=r(a)$ where $\deg(r)<\deg(m_a)$. My point is that the same method can simply be used to show that if $\deg(f)=n$ then the cosets $1+(f), x+(f),...,x^{n-1}+(f)$ are a basis of $K[x]/(f)$ over $K$. That can give a more direct solution to parts $(a)$ and $(b)$.

Comment: As for part $(c)$, try to define $\mathbb{F}_3[x]\to \mathbb{F}_3[x]/(x^2+2x+2)$ by sending $x\to 2x+(x^2+2x+2)$.

Comment: Probably you intended *a field isomorphism* instead of  *a body isomorphism*. The term for *a field* resembles the word for *a body* at least in German and French, possibly several other languages also :-)

Comment: Seconding Mark's hint for part (c). After all, $q(-X)=p(X)$, recalling that $2=-1$ here.

Comment: thank you very much for your help @Asigan , but I really dont know how to proceed for b). I know that a basis for $K(a)$ (since we have that $p(X)$ has degree $2$) could be $S=\{1,a\}$ but I dont know how can this help me.

Comment: @Mark thank you too but can you explain me better your hint for c) ?

Comment: @MarcoDiGiacomo Extend the map to a homomorphism and show its kernel is precisely $(x^2+x+2)$.

Answer (score 0):

This should be a comment, but it is too long.

Denote $(X^2+X+2)=I$. So we have the diagram: (Note that $\mathbb{F}_3[X]/I$ is not an extension of $\mathbb{F}_3$ *in the set-theoretical sense*. $\mathbb{F}_3[X]/I$ is an extension of $(\mathbb{F}_3+I)/I$ in the set-theoretical sense, and we have the obvious isomorphism $(\mathbb{F}_3+I)/I\cong \mathbb{F}_3$ as indicated in the diagram.)

[image]

Since $\{1,a\}$ is a basis for $\mathbb{F}_3(a)$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{F}_3$, and they are image of $1+I$ and $x+I$ under
the isomorphism $ g(x)+I\mapsto g(a)$ respectively, therefore
$1+I$ and $x+I$ is a basis for $\mathbb{F}_3[X]/I$ as a vector space over $(\mathbb{F}_3+I)/I$.